# Uploading a file with webdriverio and open modal

Tags: webdriver-io

I'm having this problem:
At the website I'm trying to test with webdriverio, it has this functionality:

1. You click a button to upload a file (a window opens to choose your local file)
2. You select your file and click Accept.
3. When you click Accept, a modal opens and gives you a progress bar and also some mandatory inputs  to continue the process and the test.

In other cases, uploading the file with this:
https://webdriver.io/blog/2019/06/25/file-upload/
it works fine!

But in this case, I need to open the modal after you click Accept at the window (anyway I'm not really clicking on Accept button at the locals file window, so probably this should be solve before, but I don't know how to do it)… and its not happening.

Thanks for the help!